# How to merge on a relationship between three existing nodes in Cypher?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Nodes `A`, `B`, and `C` already exist. I want to merge the node `Z` **between `A`, `B`, and `C`**. I know that I can merge between 2 of the nodes as follow:
`MERGE (A)-[:HAS]->(Z)<-[:SENT]-(B)`. However, I am curious how I could also merge with `C`?

```
                              +-------+
                              |       |
                              |  A    |
                              |       |
                              +---+---+
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |
                                  | HAS
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |
                             +----+-----+
                             |          |
                             |    Z     |
                             |          |
                             |          |
                             +----------+
                             |          |
                             |          |
                             |          |              +-----------+
+----------+                 |          |              |           |
|          |                 |          |              |           |
|          |                 |          |              |           |
|   B      +-----------------+          +--------------+    C      |
|          |        SENT                      RECV'D   |           |
|          |                                           |           |
|          |                                           |           |
+----------+                                           +-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match all your nodes and keep the identifiers around and then re-use those identifiers.

```
MATCH (a:Node {name: 'A'})
MATCH (b:Node {name: 'B'})
MATCH (c:Node {name: 'C'})
MERGE (z:Node {name: 'Z'})
MERGE (a)-[:HAS]->(z)
MERGE (b)-[:SENT]->(z)
MERGE (c)-[:RECEIVED]->(z)
```

Comment: Though take note, if there is potential for a relationship to already exist between two of those nodes, you'll want to merge each of the 3 relationships separately, otherwise you risk merging in a duplicate relationship. For example, if there was already an `(a)-[:HAS]->(z)` relationship, the longer MERGE would create an extra :HAS relationship between `a` and `z`.